# Redux state is undefined, nested objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm building a game of sorts that keeps track of correct and incorrect answers using redux but whenever I try to update my state, I'm getting an error saying it's undefined.

Here's my state slice:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import type { PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  flags: { correct: 0, incorrect: 0 },
  languages: { correct: 0, incorrect: 0 },
  regions: { correct: 0, incorrect: 0 },
  currency: { correct: 0, incorrect: 0 },
  capitals: { correct: 0, incorrect: 0 },
  start: false,
};

const gameSlice = createSlice({
  name: "game",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addError(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      switch (action.payload) {
        case "flags":
          state.flags.incorrect++;
          break;
        case "languages":
          state.languages.incorrect++;
          break;
        case "regions":
          state.regions.incorrect++;
          break;
        case "currency":
          state.currency.incorrect++;
          break;
        case "capitals":
          state.capitals.incorrect++;
          break;
      }
    },
    addCorrect(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      switch (action.payload) {
        case "flags":
          state.flags.correct++;
          break;
        case "languages":
          state.languages.correct++;
          break;
        case "regions":
          state.regions.correct++;
          break;
        case "currency":
          state.currency.correct++;
          break;
        case "capitals":
          state.capitals.correct++;
          break;
      }
    },
  },
});

export const { addError, addCorrect } = gameSlice.actions;
export default gameSlice.reducer;
```

My main.tsx (I'm using ApiProvider and Provider, maybe that's the problem?):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import { ApiProvider } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { apiSlice } from "./features/api/apiSlice";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./features/app/store";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ApiProvider api={apiSlice}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ApiProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And the function that's making the call:

```
  function handleClick(
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>,
    country: string
  ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (country === region) {
      alert("correct!");
      dispatch(addCorrect("regions"));
      setRandom(Math.floor(Math.random() * 249) + 1);
    } else {
      dispatch(addError("regions"));
    }
  }
```

Everything's imported and there are no syntax errors but every time I try to run the app, I get an Uncaught TypeError: game.state is undefined

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it's the use of both `ApiProvider` and `Provider`. The `ApiProvider` is like "redux-lite" if you have an app that ***doesn't*** already have Redux integrated and you just want to add the API service code. The `apiSlice` reducer should already be configured in the regular `store` object passed to `Provider`.

Comment: Okay got it to work thanks! I removed the ApiProvider and put the reducer path into the Provider store